# SQL Server database design for high volume stock market price data

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlperformance

I am writing application to store and retrieve stock market price data which the data is inserted on daily basis. I am storing the data for each asset (Stock) and for most of the market in the world. This is my current design of the tables

**Country** table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List_Country]
(
    [CountryId] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CurrenyCode] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [CurrencyName] [nvarchar](50) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.List_Country] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CountryId] ASC)
)
```

**Asset** table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List_Asset]
(
    [AssetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CountryId] [char](2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.List_Asset] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AssetId] ASC)
)
```

Foreign key constraint on **Country**:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[List_Asset] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.List_Asset_dbo.List_Country_CountryId] 
    FOREIGN KEY([CountryId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[List_Country] ([CountryId])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

**Stock_Price** table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock_Price_Data]
(
    [StockPriceDataId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AssetId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriceDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Open] [int] NOT NULL,
    [High] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Low] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Close] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Stock_Price_Data] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StockPriceDataId] ASC)
)
```

Foreign key constraint on **Asset**:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stock_Price_Data] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Stock_Price_Data_dbo.List_Asset_AssetId] 
    FOREIGN KEY([AssetId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[List_Asset] ([AssetId])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The concern I have at the moment is Stock_Price_Data table would be filled with high volume rows, i.e. For a specific market in a country, there can be easily 20,000 assets. Thus, in a year (260 days of trading) , I could potentially have 5.2 million rows for each country.

The application does not restrict a user from accessing data other than default country (which is setup during login).

Is it a good idea to have separate table (i.e. Stock_Price_Data_AU) for each country? Or is there a better way to design the database for the above scenario?

-Alan-

Comment: That is not a huge amount of data. If you have issues, then revisit your design.

Comment: If inserted daily I would consider Stock_Price to just have PK of [AssetId], [PriceDate].  Is there any real purpose of [StockPriceDataId].

Comment: If you maintain data in single table then the maintenance is better, only create indexes on table so that data retrieve will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I'd drop the _data from the table name - its overkill.
If you are reasonably certain that the users will always filter the data by Country  - ie only looking at 1 country at a time then I'd consider partitioning the table by Country ID - this way SQL Server will use partition elimination to pick only the relevant data. This way you get the ease of maintenance from 1 table but you get the performance as if it is a separate table per country. (I'm assuming you have Enterprise Edition) If your load works on a per country basis too then you can even switch out the partition and then drop the indexes to get even faster loads.